# how to validate a multi select list with simple scripted validator for a default value?

Tags: jira, custom-fields

I have a scenario:

There are two fields, one is a 'Text field' and another is a 'Multi select list', these two fields appear only during a
   transition.

Multi select list field is always mandatory and the text field should be made mandatory based on the value in selected in the list.
   Also, the multi select list has a value "None" which is by default in
   the Jira

I have written two scripted validator for these:

((cfValues["Test multi"]*.value.contains("Value 1") || cfValues["Test
   multi"]*.value.contains("Value 2")) && cfValues['Text field']) - LHS

|| - OR

(!cfValues["Test multi"] || cfValues["Test
   multi"]*.value.contains("Value 3")) - RHS

Basically, the above defines: If value 1 and value 2 from the list are chosen and the 'Text field' is empty then show error that this field is required. If Value 3 is chosen then the 'Text field' is not mandatory.
But the problem here is, LHS || RHS never works fine, although they individually work perfect.
I have tried all the combination now viz cfValues["Test multi"] != null and cfValues["Test multi"]?.value != null etc. Nothing seem to work, Am I doing anything trivial? Please suggest.

Thanks,
Hemanth

Answer (score 0):

What exactly doesn't work fine? The conditions are written correctly so it should let you continue without `Text field` being mandatory whenever the value of `Test multi` is None or "Value 3". The only problem I can see is that whenever the values are for example "Value 1" and "Value 3", your `Text field` is not mandatory. This can be fixed by rewriting second condition as:

```
!(cfValues["Test multi"].value.contains("Value 1") || cfValues["Test multi"].value.contains("Value 2"))
```

If that is not the problem, please specify what is wrong.

Comment: The condition you mentioned is not what I am looking at. If the value 1 and value 2 are chosen then the text field should be mandatory, If no value in the multi select is chosen or if the value selected is value 3 then the transition should not be stopped from happening. My current script is LHS || RHS, but it not serving the purpose, I know the conditions are right but not sure why it is failing, by failing I mean, even if none of the values are chosen in the multi select, the transition is taking place, which is not desired. Hope this explains.

Comment: Well, this is even more confusing as " If no value in the multi select is chosen or if the value selected is value 3 then the transition should not be stopped from happening" and "even if none of the values are chosen in the multi select, the transition is taking place, which is not desired" seem to demand two types of behavior for the same situation. I guess the problem is you want the "None" value to behave differently than "nothing selected" - I don't think that is possible in Jira. If you want a behavior like this, You'll most likely need a fourth value.